# Assigning z values to polygon feature vertices in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, dem, arcgis-10.5

I am trying to assign z values to vertices of rectangular polygon features in ArcGIS 10.5 by using a DEM raster. I do not want to assign min, max, or mean z values to the polygons themselves, but I am eventually trying to visualize my polygon as a TIN-like surface in another program (EVS) without producing a TIN; the final result must be a polygon. I've tried the Interpolate Shape tool, but it seemed to assign z values to points within the rectangular polygon features as well, creating a very large and unmanageable shape.

Comment: Interpolate shape has "vertices" option.

Comment: I did select this box when using Interpolate Shape, and the result was a polygon with more than just the feature vertices' z-values

Comment: Add geometry attributes, point count, on original and maybe simplify shapes with tiny tolerance.